# RaspberryPi GPSプログラム(python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps

RaspberryPiに接続したGPSモジュールからGPSデータ（タイムスタンプ・緯度・経度）を取得して繰り返し保存するプログラムを書きました。保存されたCSVファイルのタイムスタンプを見るとおよそ1秒に1回ごとに記録されています。1秒で５回は記録したいのですが、どのように実装すればよいですか？

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#GPS Program

import serial
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

args = sys.argv

data1= '$GPGGA'
data2= '$GPGLL'
data3= '$GPRMC'

s = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=10)
s.readline()

while 1:
        s = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=10)
        s.readline()
        sentence = s.readline().decode('utf-8')
        li = sentence.split(',')

        # NMEAのGPGGAからUTC,緯度,経度を取得してCSVファイルに保存
        if data1 in li[0]:
                timeutc = li[1]
                lat     = li[2]
                lon     = li[4]
                w = pd.DataFrame([[timeutc,lon,lat]])
                w.to_csv(args[1], index=False, encoding="utf-8", mode='a', header=False)

        # NMEAのGPGLLからUTC,緯度,経度を取得してCSVファイルに保存
        if data2 in li[0]:
                timeutc = li[5]
                lat     = li[1]
                lon     = li[3]
                w = pd.DataFrame([[timeutc,lon,lat]])
                w.to_csv(args[1], index=False, encoding="utf-8", mode='a', header=False)

        # NMEAのGPRMCからUTC,緯度,経度を取得してCSVファイルに保存
        if data3 in li[0]:
                timeutc = li[1]
                lat     = li[3]
                lon     = li[5]
                w = pd.DataFrame([[timeutc,lon,lat]])
                w.to_csv(args[1], index=False, encoding="utf-8", mode='a', header=False)
```

Comment: sleep等の処理を挟んでいるわけでもないので、GPSモジュールの性能がそのまま処理時間に反映されていそうな気がしますが、そもそもお使いのGPSモジュールは秒未満の精度で測位できるのでしょうか？

Comment: データシートには最大位置更新レートが5Hzとあるので可能なようです。

Comment: raspiでシリアル使ったことないですが、気になる点を。1. `serial.Serial()`でポートを開くのはループ前の１度でいいのではないでしょうか。現状１行以上送られて来ていても、開き直すことで消してしまっている気が。 2. ループ中のcsvに変換処理するを除いたら、ループは１秒に５回以上回るのでしょうか。回らないのであればおそらく`readline()`で詰まっているので、GPSモジュール側の転送間隔を変えないといけないのではと思います。

Comment: 「最大位置更新レートが5Hz」との事ですが、位置更新レートを毎秒５回に設定をしているのですか？質問にかかれたコードでは設定していると思われる箇所が見当たらないのですが。GPSモジュールの仕様は機種ごとに異なりますから、GPSモジュールの型番などを質問に追記したほうが適切な回答が得られると思います。